# webpack-dev-server не обновляет страницу

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Есть проекты по react,используется сборщик webpack, и его модуль --hot. В консоли все ок

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

bundle.js:631 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

Но при изминении файлов webpack не пересобирает наново build.js и ничего не происходит на странице.
Не работает даже пример с оф. документации.
https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html

```
/* style.css */
body {
    background: red;
}

/* entry.js */
require("./style.css");
document.write("<input type='text' />");

npm install webpack webpack-dev-server -g
npm install webpack css-loader style-loader
webpack-dev-server ./entry --hot --inline --module-bind "css=style\!css"
```

При изменении css ничего так же не происходит.

Спасибо за любые идеи!

Comment: спасибо за спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать настройку в `webpack.config.js`. Обратите внимание, что массив `entry` должен содержать:

```
bundle: [
  "webpack/hot/dev-server",
  (`${__dirname}/src/index.js`)
]
```

если вы хотите без перезагрузки обновлять javascript модули, например свои редьюсеры, то в коде нужно сделать подобным образом:

```
if (module.hot) {    
  module.hot.accept('reducers', () => {
    const nextReducer = require('./reducers').default
    store.replaceReducer(nextReducer)
  })
}
```

- Проверьте, что вы указали в браузере верный адрес hot-module-replacement сервера и порт.
- Проверьте в браузере наличие скрипта автообновления.
- Если вы не используете `contentBase`, сервер по-умолчанию генерирует файлы в том-же каталоге, что и отдаётся в браузер, проверьте что вы не назвали эти файлы одинаково, попробуйте использовать отдельные каталоги для исходников и сборки.
- Попробуйте добавить `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` в HTML-индекс.
- Webpack dev server умеет работать в двух режимах `inline` и `iframe`, попробуйте второй - тогда адрес будет `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html`
- Проверьте, обновляются ли файлы в файловой системе, если нет:
- Добавьте `--watch-poll` - это поможет обойти баги с нотификациями системы
- Попробуйте изменить лимит нотификаций:

  `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf ; sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: добавил ещё варианты в ответ

Comment: а где вариант что ни один из вариантов не сработает, так как автор реализовавший горячую замену для реакта, немного не в себе? Плагин который требует столько "доработок" не плагин и даже не заготовка, а полная фигня.

Comment: напишите в спорт-лото